# "Git GUI" context menu entry for Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, context-menu, git-gui

[Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) doesn't seem to support the extra context menu entries for "Git GUI Here" (or "Git Bash Here") when running on 64-bit systems. Is there some other way I can get an entry for "Git GUI" to show up in the context menu so that it will open the commit interface with the current folder selected?

#### Edit

I saw the installer option and made sure it was checked, even reinstalled a few times. Also removed TortoiseGit and restarted the computer, but nothing seems to help. From what I could find online I got the impression you have to mess around with building and modifying msysgit yourself to get the context entries to work on 64-bit systems, which I'm not keen on doing.

Answer (score 8):

You can just type: `regsvr32 "%PROGRAMFILES%\git\git-cheetah\git_shell_ext64.dll"` in a console window (or use Win+R).

Comment: Did you mean regsvr32 -u?

Comment: for me I had to use PROGRAMFILES(X86) but the basic principle did work, thanks!

Comment: @cadmium: No, I meant 'regsvr32' without the '-u', because the shell extension should be registered and not unregistered.

Answer (score 5):

Well I found a program called [Open++](http://dengdun.webs.com/en/openxx.htm) which lets you create custom context menu entries. Configure like so:

[image]

and then you can access in the Open++ submenu:

[image]

It's not quite as nice since it's in a submenu and it's always shown rather than only when you're in a repository, but it's better than having to choose your repository every time you start the gui.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. After installing msysgit not in the normal program directory, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have Git for Windows 1.7.6 installed on my 64-bit Windows 7 system, and the context menu entries work fine for me. It is an option in the installer.

Comment: Yeah I saw that option but it doesn't seem to do anything for me. I added more details to the question.